# NameError: name 'showturtle' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm tryin to get Python working for kid's school needs.

They were instructed to type:

```py
from turtle import*
showturtle ()
```

After pressing F5 and saving it with a random name it returns:

> File "C:/../132.py", line 1, in from turtle import* File "C:../turtle.py", line 2, in showturtle(0,0) NameError: name 'showturtle' is not defined

Googled it for a few hours now without success.

Thank you.

Comment: isn't justs show()?

Comment: You have a file called "turtle.py" which is imported instead of the `turtle` module. Rename it.

Answer (score 0):

One of your files is named `turtle.py` and python interpreter thinks you importing from this file instead of `turtle` module. Try to rename your file.